# Kio estas Esperanto sumoo?

Tags: culture, literature

Iu demandis min en la [Literatura Babilejo](https://www.telegramo.org/) se mi partoprenos al la Esperanto sumoo. Mi iomete legis pri tio en la reto, sed fakte: kio estas tio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ĝi estas esperanta legokonkurso.

http://www.esperanto-sumoo.strefa.pl/

De la retpaĝo

- Sumoo estas japana tradicia lukto. Ĉiun jaron okazas 6 konkursoj en neparaj monatoj: januaro, marto, majo, julio, septembro, kaj novembro. Unu konkurso daŭros 15 tagojn. Dum la luktokonkurso luktistoj estas grupigitaj en 5 grupoj.

Anna Lowenstein priskribis la aferon jene:

- It was a Japanese Esperantist who had the idea, and he divides the participants into groups with Japanese names, I suppose in imitation of a sumo contest. His idea is that instead of wrestling with someone else, you wrestle with yourself. When I hear the word Sumoo in Esperanto, I usually think of the book-reading contest, not wrestling!